# Android dynamic feature modules doing auth using Firebase AuthUI

Tags: android, firebase, android-architecture-navigation, firebase-console, dynamic-feature-module

Currently, i'm migrating to use dynamic feature modules in an Android project, while modularising, i've created the `onboarding` and `home` modules.

In the `onboarding` module, i've included the call for the AuthUI login/register flow with normality.. but, whe running the app, returns the following text in a Toast:

`Code:10, message:10`

I'm renewing/regenerating the android app configuration in the firebase console, but, i'm, getting worried about the main package name i try to use in the app configuration in firebase console.. ¿which one i must use in pro of getting the auth flow working?

1. the package name of the *base* module
2. the package name of the *onboarding* module

Any help is welcome.

Best regards,

Comment: @Alex Mamo
The question is for the package name to use in dynamic feature modules...  the error wich code 10, doesnt work with that

Comment: So, what you did in the end?